# Generate Outh tokens on Dafaricom. Api M-Pesa Java/kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, safari, mpesa

I've been trying to integrate the M-Pesa API into my app in Android Studio for days now and I'm trying to do this with Daraja/safaricom.co.ke portal!!  Well I'm stuck for a long time when to do authorization and generate Outh tokens to get access to my token and its expiry date. Can anyone help me how to generate token and have access to them in 2023 ??

I tried to do this through several blogs but it's been a while since they were done and the safaricom website has changed.  And there is no one who teaches clearly in 2023.